# SSD power cycle correct value per hour

Tags: ssd, smart

How many *Power Cycles* per hour are correct for a SSD drive?

I run smart and it returns me this value

```
POWER ON TIME => 116
POWER CYCLE COUNT => 72
```

Comment: Please ask **one question at a time**.

Answer (score 1):

*Power on time* indicates the total time the drive was running (powered). Idle time (when there was no read or write operation) also increases this value but standby time does not increase this time. One displayed day means 24 hours.

*Power Cycle Count* indicates the count of full hard disk power on/off cycles. It does not directly indicate imminent drive failure.

You brought not bad and not good values - these parameters do not reflect the real SSD state.